# Using DOM XPath to Set Single Value to a Variable

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I'm new at XPath and at PHP in general, and while I've seen 100 articles talking about issues similar to mine, I'm hitting a brick wall trying to find a solution. I'm hoping this is an easy one that I just couldn't figure out.

I've been using the following PHP code to retrieve the current temperature from the National Weather Service API, and my goal is to set the resulting value to a variable (e.g. $temp):

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHtmlFile('http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?lat=34.445&lon=-119.625833&product=time-series&appt=appt');
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $html );
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//value[1]" );
foreach ($nodelist as $n){
echo $n->nodeValue."\n";
}
```

The code above is working as expected, but I can't seem to store the nodeValue into a variable ($temp). Any ideas on how to store the temperature as a variable?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: what do you mean can't store? works perfectly fine on variable assignment [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OU2exf)

Comment: Where's your code where you attempted to store the nodeValue into $temp? What was the result (give evidence), and how did that differ from what you expected?

Comment: Wow. That's embarrassingly simple, @Ghost. Yep, that did it. Thanks so much!